# Meaning of dot symbol "·" in this context?

Tags: notation

In this context, what does the dot symbol "·" mean? Multiplication? I looked it up on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) but couldn't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it denotes ordinary multiplication.

See for example on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Notation_and_terminology